# Proper way to test ClickException was raised with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, python-click

I'm using Click to write a CLI and pytest to do testing. I have a command that generates an exception and throws a ClickException that I'd like to test:

```
@main.command(name="my-function")
def my_function():
    try:
        find_file()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise ClickException("You aren't in the right folder")
```

Now what I'm trying to do is write a test that ensures that that exception gets raised. This is the test I wrote but is failing:

```
def test_not_in_folder():
    runner = CliRunner()
    with runner.isolated_filesystem():
        with pytest.raises(ClickException):
            runner.invoke(cli.my_function, catch_exceptions=False)
```

What this test should do is run my function and watch for a ClickException exception. If that exception is raised, the test will pass. However when I run pytest, I get 'Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'click.exceptions.ClickException'>'.

What I do notice is if I print out 'runner.invoke(cli.my_function)', what gets returned by my command is '<Result SystemExit(1)>'.

So my question is: how do I use pytest to properly validate that my ClickException got triggered?

Answer (score -1):

I think you're on the right track. If the `ClickException` isn't being caught, it seems like `find_file` isn't throwing an error. I'd make sure that `find_file` is set up in such a way that it throws a `FileNotFoundError`.